# How do I create Cascading Dialog boxes using jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI's dialog feature found here:

**http://jqueryui.com/dialog** ([API Here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/))

I'd like to launch a bunch of these boxes in a cascading fashion.  Unfortunately I don't think that the [Position](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) option will do this for me as it seems pretty limited to very specific areas of the screen (I may be wrong through).

Take a look at this Fiddle for the code I have currently: **http://jsfiddle.net/bUFnE/1/**

Here is my JS:

```
//Code used to launch little score cards of the the leads
var boxID = 0;
$('a.manageLead').click(function() {
    boxID = boxID + 1;

    var url = this.href;

    // show a spinner or something via css
    var dialog = $('<div style="display:none" class="loading"></div>').appendTo('body');

    // open the dialog
    dialog.dialog({
        // add a close listener to prevent adding multiple divs to the document
        close: function(event, ui) {
            // remove div with all data and events
            dialog.remove();
        },
        modal: false,
        resizable: false,
        dialogClass: "dialog-box-"+boxID,
        position: { my: "center top", at: "center top" },
        title: "Lead Details"
    });

    // load remote content
    dialog.load(
        url, 
        {}, 
        function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            // remove the loading class
            dialog.removeClass('loading');
        }
    );

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      ////// THIS IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO MAKE THE MAGIC HAPPEN ///////

    var modalTop    = Number($('.dialog-box-'+boxID).css("top").replace("px", "")) + 20;
    var modalLeft   = Number($('.dialog-box-'+boxID).css("left").replace("px", "")) + 20;
    $('.dialog-box-'+boxID).css("top", modalTop+"px !important");
    $('.dialog-box-'+boxID).css("left", modalLeft+"px !important");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////              


    //prevent the browser to follow the link
    return false;               

});
```

If you click the link multiple times and move the newly opened dialogs around, you'll see that they are just stacking on top of each other.  I'd like them to slowly creep down the page +20px top, and +20px left, then once it hits 200px to start back at the beginning again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to add offsets on your parameters for the .position function.

You can see them [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/).

Here is an updated fiddle where it works.  http://jsfiddle.net/xGsCC/

```
position: { my: ("center+"+ center + " top+" + top), at: "center top" }
```

Just change the 10 that is added to center and top to whatever you need depending on tastes.

Note: they are subtracted in the "close:" function as well to keep them from eventually overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

your `position` argument is:

```
{ my: "center top", at: "center top" }
```

which puts each new dialog at the center top of its parent.  You never vary this argument, so of course every dialog will appear in the same place every time.

According to the jQueryUI position docs, you can specify offsets in your position strings.  So try something like this inside of your `click` function:

```
var posArgs = { my: "center top", at: "center top" };

if (parent) {
    posArgs = { my: "left top", at: "left+20 top+20", of: parent };
}
```

then use the new position arguments in your call to `dialog`, and then remember to store the new dialog as the parent of the next dialog:

```
dialog.dialog({
// add a close listener to prevent adding multiple divs to the document
    close: function(event, ui) {
        // remove div with all data and events
        dialog.remove();
    },
    modal: false,
    resizable: false,
    dialogClass: "dialog-box-"+boxID,
    position: posArgs,
    title: "Lead Details"
});
parent = dialog;
```

I'll let you handle the wrapping around of coordinates, and the error-checking if dialogs are closed and stuff.  Good luck!