# HTML Open cascading Dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not very knowledgebale in Javascript and JQuery, and I'm wondering whether what I want to do is possible.

I have a main HTML page.  From it, I create  and display a dialog as follows :

```
function createBox(id)
{
    wk= executeAjax("#myBox1","proc1.php",myParms); 
    $( "#myBox1").dialog( "option", "height", 400 );
    $( "#myBox1").dialog( "option", "width", 600 ); 

    $( "##myBox1").dialog( "option", "title", id);
    $( "#myBox1".dialog( "open" );
```

}

This works fine, my dialog window is correctly created and displayed.

What I want to know if it is possible from this dialog window, to also create and display another dialog window  ?  Possibly without closing the previous one.   And so forth (cascading windows...).

If so,  how to do ? Because I tried an got the following message :

**Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'**

If it is possible, example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This related question may help you:
[How do I create Cascading Dialog boxes using jQuery UI?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116285/how-do-i-create-cascading-dialog-boxes-using-jquery-ui

Comment: Could you please write english?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and the JQueryUI documentation supports the concept.  Here's an example of two dialogs that open at the same time.  You want three so you have to implement a click function on the button you want putting this same exact code into that function.  JQuery takes care of the rest.

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#dialog-message2").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Start first taking out the AJAX call just to get it running then put in the AJAX call and tell us what's going on.